# batch importing node data -- via database?

Tags: 7, nodes, batch-operations

I'm looking to migrate an existing site to Drupal. I have a a content type on the new Drupal site that will eventually hold some 1500 nodes. Of course, I don't want to enter each one in the form on the admin side; I'd like to input them programmatically, from a script.

What I'm wondering is if I can do plain old SQL INSERTS into the node and related tables, and have my nodes ready to use. Assuming I do the inserts correctly, will the nodes just be there when I fire up Drupal? Or will I need to touch some other parts of the site?

Or is there another way, like a module for batch importing?

This is for Drupal 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two routes you can take.

One uses the [Migrate](http://drupal.org/project/migrate) module usually in conjunction with [Table Wizard](http://drupal.org/project/tw).  This gives you a web front end for doing an import with field mapping, and other nicities.  EDIT: just saw that TW doesn't have a D7 version.

The other is a custom import script.  The script does the Drupal bootstrap process, queries the remote database, creates a `$node` and then does a [node_save](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_save).  This is a little more complex, but not that hard.

I have been doing the later on new projects, and is easy to adapt to XML, CSV, or other data sources.

Comment: Can you elaborate further on your method for doing the custom import script? I have an external database that I need to turn into Nodes, the only difference is that I also need to be able to run an "update" every now and then if the database changes. How does one make a module to query a remote db, create nodes, add menu items, etc?

Comment: The script dpes the bootstrap process just like index.php or cron.php, then does the database connection and query.  You then create nodes and do node_save().  Here is a start: http://acquia.com/blog/migrating-drupal-way-part-i-creating-node

Answer (score 1):

There is [Node Export](http://drupal.org/project/node_export) which would probably do and of course [Feeds](http://drupal.org/project/feeds). I'd recommend using a module rather than plain SQL because of all the small things Drupal does when creating a node. It's just easier really.

Comment: I'm not coming from another Drupal installation, but just a plain old LAMP website. Would Node Export help me?

Comment: Well then no, Node Export probably wouldn't work. Feeds however with Feeds XPath parser (http://drupal.org/project/feeds_xpathparser) would be what I would do.